# How to change line width and colour in R? And add a title?

Tags: r

I started coding with R and generated a sequence from -4 to 4 with 0,2 steps in part of an assignment. Afterwards I plotted y = x2 with x being the previously generated sequence using the line type of plot, I want to make the line width three and make it in green. Furthermore I want to add a title to the graph e.g. Dangerous Function. How can I do this, what is the code in R?

```
x <- (-40 : 40) / 5
y <- x ^ 2
plot ( y, type = " l " )
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wit `col=...` and `lwd=...`

```
x <- (-40 : 40) / 5
y <- x ^ 2
plot (y, type = "l", col="red", lwd=4 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Data

```
x <- (-40 : 40) / 5
y <- x ^ 2
```

## Plot code

```
plot(
  x = x,
  y = y,
  type = "l",
  #Color
  col = "green",
  #Line size
  lwd = 3,
  #Title
  main = "Dangerous function"
  )
```

## Result

[image]